# How to apply Domain Shared session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have the one application that can be access from 2 different domains. the application shows data depending on the domain used.

I need the client who logged in domain1 will be also logged in within domain2 access.

Answer (score 0):

Its not so easy as its sound because a cookie is used for the validation and the cookie can not be set from different domains.

Read this post on meta on how stackoverflow make it work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work

Also you can read the [Global Network auto-login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) article.